# How to import Intellij Plugin project

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, import

I have silly question. How can I import Intellij plugin project into intellij? I developed some code for intellij plugin, I have pushed changes to git (on this computer, intellij saw project as plugin project, I could easly run it, debug it).
Now I wanted to continue work in home, so I have check outed repository from git, I have imported intellij project into intellij (the same version). In the project tree I see META-INF folder with plugin.xml, I have selected Intellij SDK for it, I have added community edition sources to class path, but when i try to run it, it tells me that Intellij cannot find plugin.xml file. I checked configuration and I don't have a tab in Project settings to configure it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I resolved the issue.
I just created new project and I selected Intellij Platform Plugin, next I have named project same as the project name on githube and I pass the path to that github project. It overwritten configuration and now intellij sees that project as plugin project.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. There must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Also facing the same problem.